# joda ArrayIntList(5000000) vs int[5000000] Memory Consumption

Tags: java, collections, ram

I compared (with netbeans profiler) some java collections and found out that ArrayIntList take *much more* memory than flat array even if you create it with the same initial capacity. And according to its source code it just create the same array inside. So I don't understand.

You can see source code below.

[image]

```
class ProfileFlatArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final int LEN = 5000000;
        int[] array = new int[LEN];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            array[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        for (int i = LEN - 1; i > LEN / 2; i--) {
            array[i] = 0;
        }

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.gc();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.print(array[rand.nextInt(LEN / 2 - 2)]);

    }
}
```

And Joda:

```
class ProfileArrayIntList {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final int LEN = 5000000;
        ArrayIntList array = new ArrayIntList(LEN);

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            array.add(i, rand.nextInt());
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        for (int i = LEN - 1; i > LEN / 2; i--) {
            array.removeIntAt(i);
        }
        array.optimize();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.gc();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.print(array.get(rand.nextInt(LEN / 2 - 2)));

    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will resize after a certain amount of adds to keep the O(1) amortized insertion time. So the capacity of the list might be bigger than your initial seed. EDIT I've seen your `optimize`, so scratch that overallocation.

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying to debug this thing, but joda-primitives compiled without -g option.

Comment: I've checked out that inner array's length equals LEN all the time.

Comment: I mean before first `Thread.sleep` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of the call

```
array.optimize();
```

It compacts a new array by first allocating an array of a smaller size. This results into a memory bump. Then the old array is GC-ed and this results into the memory lowering. So at the end of the day `optimize()` freed half of the used memory.